# How to parse xml and extract elements and write to new xml with specified condition

Tags: xml, perl

I need to extract the xml elements from the given xml when  values is null or NA .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <log>
    <logentry revision="21754">
    <author>Madhu</author>
    <date>2015-05-12</date>
    <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
    <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
   <Description>HotFix_MaxConnectionReduction.dBAssembly.xml file in Release-  Branch</Description>
   <HP_Code_ReviewID>CR1234</HP_Code_ReviewID>
   <Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
   <Deployment_Change_Description>NA
   </Deployment_Change_Description>
   </logentry>
   <logentry revision="21779">
   <author>sudha</author>
   <date>2015-05-19</date>
   <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
   <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
   <Description> Adding Release-Branch</Description>
   <HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
   <Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
   <Deployment_Change_Description>NA
   </Deployment_Change_Description>
 </logentry>
<logentry revision="21808">
<author>sudha</author>
<date>2015-05-25</date>
<QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
<Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
<Description>  modifying 15.6.1 in PP Release-Branch to bring new spaces in modules </Description>
<HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
<Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
<Deployment_Change_Description>NA
</Deployment_Change_Description>
</logentry>
</log>
```

I need to extract the xml elements when  values are null or NA

and create new xml to process

Expected Output from the above sample is  (“ HP_Code_ReviewID tag values is NA” )

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <log>
<logentry revision="21808">
<author>sudha</author>
<date>2015-05-25</date>
<QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
<Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
<Description>  modifying 15.6.1 in PP Release-Branch to bring new spaces in modules </Description>
<HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
<Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
<Deployment_Change_Description>NA
</Deployment_Change_Description>
</logentry>
</log>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [ask]. You need to show us what you have tried, as we are not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has an excellent `XML::Twig` library that can be used for XML parsing and solving problems as you outline. I will offer you a starter example, but please be aware - Stack Overflow is about helping you solve problems with your code, not for writing code for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented_a',
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'HP_Code_ReviewID' => sub {
            if ( $_->text =~ m/NA/ ) { $_->parent->print }
        }
    }
)->parse( \*DATA );

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <log>
    <logentry revision="21754">
    <author>Madhu</author>
    <date>2015-05-12</date>
    <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
    <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
   <Description>HotFix_MaxConnectionReduction.dBAssembly.xml file in Release-  Branch</Description>
   <HP_Code_ReviewID>CR1234</HP_Code_ReviewID>
   <Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
   <Deployment_Change_Description>NA
   </Deployment_Change_Description>
   </logentry>
   <logentry revision="21779">
   <author>sudha</author>
   <date>2015-05-19</date>
   <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
   <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
   <Description> Adding Release-Branch</Description>
   <HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
   <Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
   <Deployment_Change_Description>NA
   </Deployment_Change_Description>
 </logentry>
<logentry revision="21808">
<author>sudha</author>
<date>2015-05-25</date>
<QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
<Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
<Description>  modifying 15.6.1 in PP Release-Branch to bring new spaces in modules </Description>
<HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
<Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
<Deployment_Change_Description>NA
</Deployment_Change_Description>
</logentry>
</log>
```

This sets a twig handler for `HP_Code_ReviewID' and if the text in it contains`NA` prints the parent element.

Note that this isn't - explicitly - valid XML, because it only captures the `logentry` element. However you can do things with XML::Twig like deleting elements that *don't* match and then display the rest of the document.

This prints:

```
  <logentry revision="21779">
    <author>sudha</author>
    <date>2015-05-19</date>
    <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
    <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
    <Description> Adding Release-Branch</Description>
    <HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="21808">
    <author>sudha</author>
    <date>2015-05-25</date>
    <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
    <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
    <Description>  modifying 15.6.1 in PP Release-Branch to bring new spaces in modules </Description>
    <HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
  </logentry>
```

To preserve these in context, you'd - basically - have to delete the things that *didn't* match:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented_a',
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'logentry' => sub {
            if ( not $_->first_child_text('HP_Code_ReviewID') =~ m/NA/ ) {
                $_->delete;
            }
        }
    }
)->parse( \*DATA )->print;
```

(same `DATA` block as above).

This will print:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
  <logentry revision="21779">
    <author>sudha</author>
    <date>2015-05-19</date>
    <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
    <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
    <Description> Adding Release-Branch</Description>
    <HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
    <Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
    <Deployment_Change_Description>NA
   </Deployment_Change_Description>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="21808">
    <author>sudha</author>
    <date>2015-05-25</date>
    <QC_ID>NA</QC_ID>
    <Rally_ID>US4940</Rally_ID>
    <Description>  modifying 15.6.1 in PP Release-Branch to bring new spaces in modules </Description>
    <HP_Code_ReviewID> NA</HP_Code_ReviewID>
    <Deployment_Change_Needed>No</Deployment_Change_Needed>
    <Deployment_Change_Description>NA
</Deployment_Change_Description>
  </logentry>
</log>
```